# How to upload VHD to Azure BLOB storage in parallel?

Tags: c#, azure

I already read the following [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazurestorage/2010/04/10/using-windows-azure-page-blobs-and-how-to-efficiently-upload-and-download-page-blobs/)

I was wondering how to combine using `Parallel.Foreach` and `pageBlob.WritePages(memoryStream, vhdOffset + offsetToTransfe)` to improve performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the upload library provided by the Azure Storage team: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introducing-azure-storage-data-movement-library-preview-2/

Comment: Is it official recommendation? I don't understand why do I need to use this library if Azure provide opportunity to upload by using native methods like WritePages()?

Comment: AzCopy has been a popular, performant blob copy tool for a while. There have been many requests to provide that performance in a library - and thus is the result. Obviously, you could code it yourself using the standard library, but you likely couldn't know all the best practices fir optimizing the performance if an upload.

Comment: How can I use this library when I write to page blob? Do you have any links?

Comment: How to upload with offset using this library? `TransferManager.UploadAsync(stream, _blob, null, sharedTransferContext, CancellationToken.None).Wait();` where I can put offset?